# Как убрать отступы в RecyclerView, которые возникают при загрузке изображений из интернета

Tags: android, xml, recyclerview

Необходимо сделать галерею изображений. Делаю ее при помощи `RecyclerView`. Скачиваю изображение из интернета, добавляю его в `ImageView`, потом при помощи адаптера загоняю это в `RecyclerView`. Однако почему-то между изображениями появляются огромные отступы. Сначала думал, что это из-за того, что разрешение изображений очень высокое, но потом добавил `scaleType`, но ничего не изменилось. Пробовал добавлять нулевые паддинги/марджины - все равно не помогло. В чем проблема? Вот `imageView`, в которую загоняю картинку:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:padding="4dp"/>
```

Вот пример картинки: https://image.ibb.co/jmHhB8/alicia_vikander_large.jpg

И вот разметка `RecyclerView`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/previewImages"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager" />
```

В чем проблема?

**UPD**

Вот как это выглядит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вы используете во фрагменте. То посмотрите отступы у вашего контейнера

Comment: @ВиталийРобиновский, нет, это не во фрагменте, а в активности именно

Comment: попробуйте для `ImageView` прописать атрибут `adjustViewBounds=true`, иногда помогает) А вообще - не понятно, что значит "добавляю в ImageView, потом при помощи адаптера загоняю в RecyclerView". Это как?

Comment: @Jarvis_J, извините, не совсем корректно сформулировал. Суть в том, что мой `RecyclerView` содержит только изображение. И получается, что я для каждого элемента списка создаю свой `ImageView` и добавляю это в адаптер. А после подключаю адаптер к `RecyclerView`

Comment: а сколько у вас колонок? `adjust` не помог? Вообще, судя по всему у вас фиксированная ширина (100dp) и 2 колонки, а всё остальное место просто пустота

Comment: @Jarvis_J, да,столбцов всего два. Но строка не одна,а больше. Просто из-за этих отступов они не поместились на скрине

Comment: Вы показали весь `xml` с `ImageView`? Похоже где-то у айтема стоит мач_парент